# how best to loop through an array taking into account of the index in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I've seen this thread talking about map: [Map function in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983163/map-function-in-matlab)

As a result, I was wondering whether there are similar ways to do it taking into consideration of the indices. Such as if i want to do something like (x_i)^i.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example:

```
>> x = randi(10, [1 5])
x =
     9     7     4    10     1

>> x.^(1:numel(x))
ans =
    9      49    64   10000  1
```