# MATLAB: how to apply function componentwise

Tags: matlab

Say I have a function calculateStuff(x) that takes in a scalar as parameter and returns a scalar.

Say I have a vector X and I want to apply calculateStuff on every component in X, and get a vector of the results in return and store it in a new vector Y.

Clearly Y=calculateStuff(X) is illegal, is there a way I can do this besides looping?

Comment: Isn't that called `map`?

Comment: @Robert: Please don't make [multiple posts of the same question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986451/matlab-how-to-apply-functions-componentwise)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map function in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983163/map-function-in-matlab)

Answer (score 16):

You have three options:

1. modify `calculateStuff` so that it can take arrays and return arrays
2. write a loop
3. use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) to hide the loop: `Y = arrayfun(@calculateStuff,X)`

Answer (score 9):

Most Matlab operations will let you input a matrix and return a matrix.  You should be able to re-write calculateStuff() to take a matrix and return a matrix.  That is generally MUCH faster than using a *for* loop.  Loops in Matlab are very expensive time-wise.

The sorts of things you need to look at are "dot" versions of normal operations. For example instead of

```
y = z * x;
```

do

```
y = z .* x;
```

The first will do a matrix multiplication, which is probably not what you want when vectorizing code.  The second does an element-by-element multiplication of *z* and *x*.

See [here](http://math.uc.edu/~kingjt/matlab/tutorial_v4.html) and search for "The dot operations".