# MATLAB: how to apply functions componentwise?

Tags: matlab

I have a function `calculateStuff(x)` that takes in a scalar as parameter and returns a scalar.

I have a vector `X` and I want to apply `calculateStuff` on every component in `X`, and get a vector of the results in return and store it in a new vector `Y`.

Clearly `Y=calculateStuff(X)` is illegal. Is there a way I can do this besides looping?