# Matlab - running a function with parameters for every element of an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Matlab has a nice property that scalar functions (such as sin) can work on arrays, operating on any element of the array and returning an array as result.

I have a scalar function `f(x,p)` where `x` is a scalar, and `p` is a parameter (actually an array of parameters). Given a fixed parameter `p`, I wish to run `f(x,p)` on an array `A`. In a language like Ruby it would look like this:

```
A.collect{|x| f(x,p)}
```

But I have no idea how to do it in Matlab for functions that accept parameters and not only the scalar from the array I want to operate on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map function in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983163/map-function-in-matlab)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MATLAB equivalent is to supply a function handle taking only a single argument, and sending it to [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html).

```
arrayfun( @(x) f(x, p), A )
```

For example,

```
A = 1:10;
p = 2;
arrayfun( @(x) x.^p, A )
```

Note that the [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) creates a closure, capturing the value of `p`.