# How to apply a function to individual elements of a array/vector

Tags: arrays, function, matlab

I have a function f(x,a,b,c) and i want to use plot() to display it. That means i have to compute f(x) for each of my x and store them in a vector to use plot().

How can i apply my function to each element of x individually? My function requires 3 arguments aside from the value of x. I've tried arrayfun() but can't seem to get it working...

```
x = linspace(0.008,0.08);

a = 0.005;
b = 0.0015;
re = (1.23*40*0.005)/(1.79*10^-5);

y = arrayfun(@f, x, a, b, re);
plot(y);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: related question: [Map function in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983163/map-function-in-matlab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html):

```
y = arrayfun(@(x) f(x, a, b, re), x);
```